# PDF output: Apache FOP or <cfdocument> tag using coldfusion 11

Tags: apache, pdf, coldfusion, apache-fop, coldfusion-11

I am moving coldfusion 9 window to coldfusion 11 linux. I have an application that is to generate PDF output.  The last developer utilized Apache FOP library to depoly PDF outputs many years ago:

```
<CFSaveContent Variable="FOData">
<CFOutput>
<!-- root of document, set common attributes, will be inherited by all lower      tags -->
<fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
  font-family="serif"
  font-size="12pt"
  text-align="left">
  ...
</CFSaveContent>
</CFOutput>
```

It doesn't work running on Coldfusion 11. I have blank page(s) on PDF output. I have Apache FOP 0.20. I downloaded new version FOP 2.0.  I found out there are many changes need to be done on my source codes if I use new FOP.

My question is should I keep this FOP depolyment or switch to `<cfdocument format="PDF">` tag.

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: cfdocument is the better option than FOP. No overhead to learn new syntax. No third party library less maintenance problem. HTML syntax which you probably know at the back of your mind. Syntax is as easy as
  <cfdocument format="PDF">html</cfdocument>

  cfDocument(format="PDF") { writeOutput(html); };

Comment: There is no single definitive answer.  Which is "best" for *your* needs really depends on a number of factors, such as the quantity and content of the pdf's you need to generate, as well as the time cost of code conversion.  Also, keep in mind that while CFDocument is simpler to use *initially*, it has some serious quirks and limitations (just search the archives and bug database).